# How to change the cursor default to pointer in Vuetify component

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I want to change cursor default to pointer when active autocomplete in Vuetify.
I tried to make css code to change cursor.
but mouse drag on the autocomplete bottom, cursor change "text" style like "I beem". I want to show the "pointer " style.
I couldn't find out any idea Vuetify web site.
Does anyone have idea?

```html
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row
        align="center"
      >
        <v-col cols="12">
          <v-autocomplete
            v-model="value"
            :items="items"
            dense
            filled
            label="Filled"
            class="test_cursor"
          ></v-autocomplete>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      items: ['foo', 'bar', 'fizz', 'buzz'],
      values: ['foo', 'bar'],
      value: null,
    }),
  }
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.test_cursor{
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking. I'm not overly familiar with Vuetify but even just looking at the [examples in the documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/), items in the list and selected items all have the pointer (hand) cursor style

Comment: Mr.Phil) yeah, I tried like below. it works, but i want drag cursor on the autocomplete and cursor changing pointer.
<v-autocomplete
            v-model="value"
            :items="items"
            dense
            filled
            label="Filled"
            class="test_cursor"
          ></v-autocomplete>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.test_cursor{
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

Comment: Sorry, I edit my question and my bad explanation. I drag the on autocomplete , cursor change pointer to I beem style. but I don't want to change cursor style when I drag the mouse on the autocomplete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `cursor` is set to `text` (which appears as the "I-beam" you mention), but you can change the `v-autocomplete`'s cursor by targeting the `input` in your CSS:

```css
.test_cursor input {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      states: [
        { name: 'Florida', abbr: 'FL', id: 1 },
        { name: 'Georgia', abbr: 'GA', id: 2 },
        { name: 'Nebraska', abbr: 'NE', id: 3 },
        { name: 'California', abbr: 'CA', id: 4 },
        { name: 'New York', abbr: 'NY', id: 5 },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

```css
.test_cursor input {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.3.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.3.5/dist/vuetify.css">

<v-app id="app">
  <v-autocomplete
                  class="test_cursor"
                  :items="states"
                  item-text="name"
                  label="State"
                  ></v-autocomplete>
</v-app>
```